# django download file from server to user's machine,or read online

Tags: django, forms, download

I am uploading some .doc and .txt documents on my server, and i'd like to have two options:
-the user to be able to download the document
-the user to be able to read it online
i've read some code for the download function, but it doesn't seem to work.

my code:

```
def download_course(request, id):
    course = Courses.objects.get(pk = id)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(/root/)
    return response

def save_course(request, classname):
   classroom = Classroom.objects.get(classname = classname)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CoursesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
           handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['course'])
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.creator = request.user
           new_obj.classroom = classroom
           new_obj.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('.')    
   else:
           form = CoursesForm()     
   return render_to_response('courses/new_course.html', {
           'form': form,
           }, 
          context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 


def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('root', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)

    destination.close()
```

any clue?
thanks!

Comment: You need to define `file_name somewhere! Is it stored in the `Courses` model? (I suppose it's meant to be Courses.course)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should the response['X-Sendfile'] be pointing to the file?  It looks like it's only pointing at '/root/', which I'm guessing is just a directory.  Maybe it should look more like this:

```
def download_course(request, id):
    course = Courses.objects.get(pk = id)
    path_to_file = get_path_to_course_download(course)

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
    return response
```

Where `get_path_to_course_download` returns the location of the download in the file system (ex: `/path/to/where/handle_uploaded_files/saves/files/the_file.doc`)

Comment: 'got unexpected argument mimetype'

Answer (score 12):

You can open a File object to read the actual file, and then start download the file like this code:

```
        path_to_file = os.path.realpath("random.xls")
        f = open(path_to_file, 'r')
        myfile = File(f)
        response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + name
        return response
```

`path_to_file`: is where the file is located on the server.
`f = open(path_to_file, 'r')` .. to read the file

the rest is to download the file.

Comment: class is `from django.core.files import File`