# django open a zip file for user to download

Tags: python, django, download, zip

Django 1.7, Python 3.4, windows apache 2.4.12 + wsgi

In my program, I generate some csv files and put them in a zip file. I would like to let the user download the zip file, either force download (after file is generated and render response) or a click of button (after display result, user has to click a button to download.)

Currently I am forcing them to download once the zip file is generated on the server.

I have referenced the following links and come up with my code below. But it is always give me this error "'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 80: character maps to " I tried to set it with utf-8 and ascii, and similar errors will be given.

referenced links:

- [django download file from server to user's machine,or read online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096649/django-download-file-from-server-to-users-machine-or-read-online)
- [how to serve downloadable zip file in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459300/how-to-serve-downloadable-zip-file-in-django)
- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/
- [Generating file to download with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908258/generating-file-to-download-with-django)

Anyone know why am I getting this error and how to get this to work?

Thank you very much!

```
zip_filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + ".zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, mode='a', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    for s in sql_request:
        // generate csv files
        zf.write(csv_file)

// close zf

zip_file = open(zip_filename, 'r')
response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'foo.zip'
return response
```

Comment: Consider serving zip files using a dedicated web server like apache / nginx. This is extremely easy to do using `XSendfile` / `X-Accel-Redirect`. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1158750/1268926

Comment: I want to point out, from your example, zipping is not useful. You should gzip-compress all output from your server anyways. It looks like there is only 1 csv file in the zip, so why bother?

Comment: @beiller There're more than one file I need to zip. How do you specify using gzip in python? I only see two compression options, one is zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED and the other is zipfile.ZIP_STORED, which is more like archiving.

Comment: @kedar Thank you for the link. I will check it out. No idea about how to setup nginx, but I will try.

Comment: I'm not sure the configuration. Usually web servers send HTML documents GZIP compressed to save bandwidth. It should do the same sending the CSV file. It's usually done "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you might need to change your `open` line to include the [`b` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

`zip_file = open(zip_filename, 'rb')`

Comment: if I add 'b' as you suggested, it give me a programming error "
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_sessio...      ^ " What is this error?

Comment: That error's coming from a very different place in Django and suggests that your database schema doesn't match your model definitions. You may need to make and apply migrations.

Comment: :) I got this error because in my setting I have set MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage' (I don't know why I have it nor do I really need it. I am a django newbie.) I commented it out and now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad to hear you found the issue :)